# Power Arduino Nano with OTG cable

Tags: power, usb, arduino-nano

I have a project that I am putting an Arduino Nano in an enclosed box that will light LEDs in a pattern. I am planning to power it with a 5 V power brick but I would like to build a way a update the code to the Arduino without needing to disassemble the box.

Could I use an OTG cable with power (OTG Y cable)  to accomplish this? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a OTG Y cable just plug it into your phone, power cable into the power source and use the third connector to connect  to your PC. (Assuming the PC only gets GND, D+ and D- and battery bank GND, 5V)

It is also possible to reprogram an Arduino with an Android device that has OTG support.
Would save you a bit of hassle.

My Android phone (LG D605) with [ArduinoDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid2) can easily upload code to my Nano and Uno.

Comment: I would be programming it with a pc. I was just wondering if I could power it from the OTG cable and still be able to connect it to the pc. The OTG cable has a micro usb, female usb for connection and male usb for power.

Comment: USB voltage is below the 6v minimum specified voltage for Vin (on a 5v board).  It might still work to a degree, but beware that what you are recommending is out of spec.  Your reference to OTG has nothing to do with what they poster is talking about, they are proposing what is basically a Y cable, that could be used with something like an Android device, but instead they want to use it with a PC, USB powerbank and the Nano - no Android involved.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My bad, I misunderstood the description. I updated the answer.